# Changing filling in QProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt, customization

how can I change the color of the filling in QProgressBar?
Is there a simple way to do it or do I have to do some stylesheet settings etc?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2007/06/12/styling-qprogressbar-and-qscrollbar/

Stylesheet and Qt Quick is what you need to explore ...

Comment: Hi, I don't really think that this would be possible using stylesheets. The reason for that is that I will loose the original appearance and this isn't acceptable in my case. The only thing I need to change is fill colour, while keeping original appearance.

Comment: When you say fill color are you talking about merely the color inside the default progress bar ? Not really a designer here :)

Comment: QProgressBar::chunk {
     background-color: #05B8CC;
     width: 20px;
 } 

Does this work for you ?

Comment: #Ankur hi, no it doesn't. if you check it, this will not change just the color. I want just color to be changed nothing else.

Comment: #Ankur so? I don't think it's actually possible to change just filling color. If anything one would have to create one's own ProgressBar.

Comment: can you please mail me the working code for the progress bar you have currently and also a png/jpg showing end result you desire. I am willing to work on it.

Comment: email address is versesane [at] gmail . com

Comment: #Ankur hi, thanks for your reply. The progress bar is native progress bar from windows 7. I don't have any working code because I do use the progress bar from qt and in this progress bar I'd like to change just the color of filling. If you could do that (make just color change) and post the code either here or to my email atch[at]wp.pl I'll be very grateful. Looking forward to hear from you. Thanks.